# Как узнать margin-left любого элемента от главного окна браузера?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Причем неважно, какую вложенность имеет элемент сам элемент, т.е. в скольких контейнерах он бы не находился, нужно найти его `marginLeft` от главного окна браузера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('selector').offset().left
```

Читаем про [offset() и position()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: да читать не особо уже надо, просто я давно использовал и подзабыл, спасибо за ответ. (думал почему $('s').offest.left не срабатывает...)

Comment: Наглядно: http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/zdVv6/